# .push() is creating duplicate table filter dropdowns when page is revisited

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, setstate

I have custom table with a filters property. 3 of the filters are hard coded, but 1 of the filters is gathered through a POST request from our API because their filter options are frequently updated in our database by non-engineering folks.

My issue is that when you hit the back button to get to the page with this custom table, a duplicate Gateways filters is added to the page. This item disappears when you refresh the page, which demonstrated to me that I am running into an issue with the State. How can I make it so the Gateways filter is only displayed once?

Here is the code for the table:

```js
       <CredcapTable
          defaultSort="created_at"
          cols={cols}
          filters={filters}
          searchFunc={this.searchFunc}
          recordMappingFunc={this.recordMappingFunc}
        />
```

Here is the function that pulls the Gateways filters from the database, which is called in componentDidMount:

```js
  private loadFilters = () => {
    searchGateways(this.props.app.api, new SearchRequest()).then((res: SearchResults<Gateway>) => {
      const opts = new Array<any>();
      opts.push({ label: "All", value: "*" });

      res.results.map((g: Gateway) => {
        opts.push({ label: `${g.name} [${g.code}]`, value: g.id });
      });

      filters.push({
        field: "gateway_id",
        label: "Gateway",
        options: opts
      });

      this.setState({ filters });

    });
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up your state on unmount?

Comment: No, I have no yet tried that...how would that look? I don't typically use componentWillUnmount at work.

Comment: Try this. 

this.setState(prevState => ({
     filters: prevState.filters.concat({
        field: "gateway_id",
        label: "Gateway",
        options: opts
      })
}));

Comment: @remelkabir yessss this worked, thank you!!!

Comment: no problem @J.Lara